# Não consigo alterar arquivos em htdocs sem criar uma cópia

Tags: aplicação-web, servidor, xampp

Boa tarde!

Estou trabalhando em um projeto web e tendo problemas na pasta htdocs. Quando faço uma alteração em um arquivo e vou conferir, a alteração não aparece na página. Para que ela apareça é necessário que eu feche o editor, crie uma cópia do folder do projeto e acesse o localhost por esta cópia. Aí a alteração aparece. Caso eu altere e queira olhar a modificação no mesmo arquivo, o site aparece como se nada tivesse sido alterado. Alguma dica de como resolver?

Comment: Antes de qualquer coisa, comece fazendo o [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender como a comunidade funciona; depois leia o guia de [Como perguntar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) para verificar como pode melhorar sua pergunta e, por fim, acesse a [central de ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help) para verificar vários artigos que te lhe ajudarão a entender melhor o site.

Answer (score 0):

São as permissões do arquivo dentro da pasta.
Se estiver usando linux, chmod -R +x /opt/lammp/htdocs
Se estiver usando windows, altere manualmente com o botão direito do mouse, ou use o comander.

Comment: Perdão, eu não entendi. Por acaso está se referindo a permissões de administrador? Porque isso já tem. Uso windows mesmo.

Comment: Isso, estou acostumado com linux. Mas altere as permissões para permitir leitura escrita para todos os usuários.